# Multiple root tables in flatbuffers

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, flatbuffers

I'm checking out Flatbuffers for implementing a communication protocol. When a message is received, it may in my case contain a number of different tables. If I understand correctly, the way to achieve this in Flatbuffers is to use a "root" table that has each possible different table in a union.

In my case, I will already know the incoming type (type is part of the header) => I do not necessarily need to be able to place each type inside a single table. However, it does not seem to be possible to mark multiple tables as "root" types. This means that if I have defined the tables `Foo` and `Bar` that I can only get either a `GetFoo()` or a `GetBar()` method for deserialization, but not both.

I am assuming that it would also be possible to split the definitions across different schema files, but since they would share some subclasses I would also need a shared schema file for the common definitions. This seems to be a bit more complicated than necessary for simple cases.

Is there another way of being able to deserialize multiple different types with Flatbuffers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Note that the generated `GetMyType()` is just short for the templated `GetRootAs<MyType>` which you can use with any type.

Comment: Ah! I hadn't looked at the code, just the docs. I'll open a ticket asking for a note in the docs.

Comment: was it added recently?  my version 2.0.0 does not have `GetRootAs`